# Не отправляется запрос на mysql из nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

Делаю мод для rage mp (gta 5) и сервер на nodejs и javascript построен.

```
mp.events.add('playerQuit', player => {
    connection.connect();  // Подключаюсь к mysql
    connection.query("INSERT INTO `users` (`nick`, `x`, `y`, `z`) VALUES ('"+player.name+"', '"+player.position['x'].toFixed(4)+"', '"+player.position['y'].toFixed(4)+"', '"+player.position['z'].toFixed(4)+"')", function(err, rows, fields)   // Делаю запрос на сохранение координат игрока
    {  
        console.log(err); // Проверяю ошибки при отправке запроса
    });
    console.log("INSERT INTO `users` (`nick`, `x`, `y`, `z`) VALUES ('"+player.name+"', '"+player.position['x'].toFixed(4)+"', '"+player.position['y'].toFixed(4)+"', '"+player.position['z'].toFixed(4)+"')"); // Делаю проверку какой запрос отправился
    connection.end(); // Закрываю соединение
});
```

В итоге в консоли дает правильный запрос, но в базе данные не появляются, если этот запрос вручную дать в phpmyadmin то данные сохранятся как надо. При этом до этого делал запрос на получение данных, все нормально передавалось.

Решение проблемы оказалось вообще не в коде, а в mysql сервере и его таймауте, слишком быстро закрывалось соединение если не давать ему команд.

Answer (score 0):

Информации мало, поэтому поделюсь своим опытом, у меня была схожая проблема, когда была кодировка неправильная установлена на MySQL сервере. А вообще предлагаю попробовать логировать запросы на MySQL сервере и ошибки тоже, а потом посмотреть чего там.

Comment: Сделал по другому систему, сначала запрос получить координаты игрока, если они есть то иду дальше если нет то значит и аккаунта нет, создаю новый и ошибка Error: Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit. Проверил логи, там только запрос на получение координат.

Comment: Проблема была вообще не в коне а в сервере mysql, таймаут подключения был маленький вот и все проблемы. Вопрос решен.